Can't reproduce virtual thread pinning (jdk 21), yet mysql not as parallel as should be
The jdk 21 doc about virtual threads (hereafter "VT")
(https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html)
is pretty clear about a synchronized block causing a thread to be pinned, or native methods, or ...
It all started with another SO question about mysql and virtual threads (Can Virtual Threads improve querying a database in Java?), and this showed that VT are not parallelizing upon mysql statements as they should (on driver prior to 9.0.0, like 8.4). I though, I can surely reproduce that in a kata.... Let's try!
I created 12 tasks at 1 thread per task, each task doing 3 blocking op of 1000ms inside a synchronized block. It should take 3x1000ms = 3seconds per task. At least on platform threads. And those platform threads never fail to do so predictably.
I wrote variations of blocking ops as Object.wait() inside s synchronized, as simple Thread.sleep() (synchronized and not), as ReentrantLock's condition.await() and as socket inputstream read() (synchronized and not). My money was on the network read, since that what mysql driver did. Also, we can see from the jdk source that object.wait() and thread.sleep() have been made VT friendly. I even tried but deleted a Pipe Input/Output Stream setup because it's all based on the same previous in-memory synchronization.
On VTs, according to the doc, I should expect synchronized and native methods, but not  reentrantlocks, to take more time, but it would depends how many carrier threads are around... They don't say.
(UPDATE: actually I found later that there are as many as cores, but extras can be created up to 256 total).
If there are only as many carrier threads as there are cores, then I have 4 carriers. I should expect my tasks to run only 4 at a time if I really pinned the VT, and the whole tasks to finish by the 9 seconds mark.
I wanted to prove that. So I wrote this complex test below.
And I failed to pin any carrier thread; (at first: see my own answer) the 12 tasks end nearly together at the 3 seconds mark.
What's even more interesting is that I started 12 threads, but 14 carriers were used at some point.
(UPDATE: this is the extra carriers expected after finding better doc: "The capture of an OS thread is compensated by temporarily adding a carrier thread to the scheduler." Ref: https://liakh-aliaksandr.medium.com/concurrent-programming-in-java-with-virtual-threads-8f66bccc6460)
To see the carried thread id, I used JNA at first, to pull the kernel 32 GetCurrentThreadId(). Later I used Foreign Function Invocation (FFI) as suggested by a commenter. I removed this JNA code since.
I will not repeat the original question's code as it is obsolete and much even if you don't read the answer too.
I really wanted to know how the older mysql driver 8.4 can pin a VT carrier to the point of reducing concurrency, and particularly how they would fix it in driver 9.0.x, but I didn't feel like reading mysql code to do that. It seemed like a single-file-sized kata was in order.
(UPDATE: so I found the way to reproduce pinning, see answer.)
(UPDATE: since the answer, commenters have noted that java 24 will implement synchronized() blocks and methods in a way that VTs can unbind from the platform threads.)

You mentioned using JDK 21 - that still pins virtual threads when blocking inside synchronized. If you want to check the corresponding source code, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk21u and not openjdk/jdk.

What exactly is the actual output of your program? What output would you expect? Are you expecting pinning with anything other than SyncWaitTask?

I mention jdk 21 only because that's when VT are officially introduced (not preview as in jdk 20). I may try open jdk too, but that's not about jdks versions. Mysql driver can pin the carrier native thread and I cannot reproduce that. That's all.
For the expected output, I stated that if I reproduced carrier pinning, one or more of the 4 variations  (when using VTs) should take more than the ideal 3 seconds to complete.

I'll add an output excerpt later when I'm back at the workstation. Thanks for your interest.

Since I do not have JNA at hands I replaced it with direct FFI calls. Then, your first example did not reproduce the problem of having too many carrier threads. It reported three carrier threads in most runs, sometimes two, sometimes four. So, maybe the JNA calls are part of the problem. You should use -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=full to determine whether critical pinning happened, instead of relying solely on execution times and observed thread ids. Your second example, “big file” does not contain a problematic scenario.

Pinning has never been a guarantee. Even if there is a synchronized  block or native. The actual details of whether these constructs generate pinning or not haven't been disclosed. That's what -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads  and JFR events for. If pinning was that simple, we probably won't need such instruments. As for 12 virtual threads that use 14 carriers ones, could you try to create at least 1000 VTs and see how many carriers they will need? P.S. @Holger above is also very correct on that topic - as usual.

To Holger, "does not contain a problematic scenario" -> that's the center of the question. How to reproduce pinning which I see with mysql driver (in the referenced question). The details of when pinning occurs are in the article referenced, if that can be considered details. I will certainly try this jvm option, thanks.

To Igor, the mysql lack of parallelism appeared within 10 threads which is why I don't try to change too much the conditions. Let's not focus on the number of carriers, that is a distraction I could have skipped.

Ok I reproduced it! preparing an updated code...

FYI, the -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=full or -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=short simply hangs the jvm in debug mode. Seems ok in run mode.

@dan1st To eliminate synchronized pinning as an issue, use Java 24 early-access. See JEP 491: Synchronize Virtual Threads without Pinning.

@BasilBourque yes but the OP mentions using JDK 21 but they also mentions "Also, we can see from the jdk source that object.wait() and thread.sleep() have been made VT friendly." which is not in JDK 21 (as you mentioned, that's integrated in 24) so I wrote that comment asking which version they are actually interested in.

object.wait() and thread.sleep() alone do not pin the carrier (tested) and I looked at the java 21 java source., not C to draw that conclusion However, synchronized() still pins the carrier (SyncSleepTask and SyncNetTask) unless the monitor is freed by .wait() (SyncWaitTask). I'm eager to test java 24 to see that synchronized pinning solved! It's sad that a preview feature (java 20) is official in LTS (21) in such a churning state. They need to backport a patch to 21 imho.

I figured how to reproduce.
I was very close, with my synchronized wait.
I needed a synchronized block, but I put a thread sleep instead, not releasing the monitor.
Here is the new code, without JNA.
Thanks for the FFI (Foreign Function Invocation) idea).
Now it is a single file too.
I thought I could shave a lot to minimize it to the reproduction, but showing the variants and how they behave is a great complement to learn.
package vttests;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.foreign.FunctionDescriptor;
import java.lang.foreign.Linker;
import java.lang.foreign.SymbolLookup;
import java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TestCustomBlockageWithVTs {
    static final boolean DEBUGGING = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().toString().contains("-agentlib:jdwp");
    static final boolean TRACELOG = false;
    
    static final int PORT = 42000;
    static final int BLOCKAGE_DURATION_MS = 1000;
    static final int NUM_REPETITION = 3;
    
    static MethodHandle getTidMH;
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("kernel32");
        SymbolLookup.loaderLookup().find("GetCurrentThreadId").ifPresent(mseg -> {
            FunctionDescriptor mdesc = FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT);
            getTidMH = Linker.nativeLinker().downcallHandle(mseg, mdesc);
        });
    }
    
    static Integer tid() {
        try {
            return getTidMH != null ? (int)getTidMH.invokeExact() : null;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    static void p(Object msg) {
        System.out.println("["
            + (Thread.currentThread().isVirtual() ? "V" : "P")
            + "/"+ Thread.currentThread().getName()
            + "("+tid()+")]: " 
            + msg
        );
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //NOTE: jdk.tracePinnedThreads hangs the JVM in debug mode
        if(!DEBUGGING)
            System.setProperty("jdk.tracePinnedThreads", "short"); //or "full"
        
        boolean useVirtual = true;
        
        runTest("synchronized waits", useVirtual, SyncWaitTask.class);
        runTest("synchronized sleep", useVirtual, SyncSleepTask.class);
        runTest("reentrant lock waits", useVirtual, RLWaitTask.class);
        runTest("reentrant lock sleep", useVirtual, RLSleepTask.class);
        runTest("sleep", useVirtual, SleepTask.class);
        
        try(Closeable startServer = startServer()) {
            runTest("net read", useVirtual, NetTask.class);
            runTest("sync net read", useVirtual, SyncNetTask.class);
        }           
    }
    
    static void runTest(String title, boolean useVT, Class<? extends AbstractBlockingTask> clazz) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> tid2id = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> id2tid = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        BiConsumer<Integer,Integer> recorder = (tid,taskId) -> {
            tid2id.computeIfAbsent(tid, _tid -> Collections.synchronizedSet(new TreeSet<>())).add(taskId);
            id2tid.computeIfAbsent(taskId, _id -> Collections.synchronizedSet(new TreeSet<>())).add(tid);
        };
        
        AtomicInteger nextTaskId = new AtomicInteger(0);
        Supplier<Runnable> taskFactory = () -> newTask(clazz, nextTaskId.getAndIncrement(), BLOCKAGE_DURATION_MS, recorder);
        
        long t = System.nanoTime();
        runTasks(title, useVT, taskFactory);
        double d = 1e-9*(System.nanoTime() - t);
        p("Whole test took " + d + " sec");
        
        double expectedLow = 1e-3 * BLOCKAGE_DURATION_MS * NUM_REPETITION;
        double expectedHigh = 1.10 * expectedLow;
        if(d<expectedLow || d>expectedHigh) {
            p("\n\n>>>>>>>>>>>> "+title+": test lasted outside of expected time of ~"+expectedLow+" sec : "+d+" sec <<<<<<<<<<\n\n");
        }
        
        p("thread-taskid mappings recorded "+tid2id.size()+" distinct native threads");
        tid2id.values().removeIf(set -> set.size()<=1);
        tid2id.forEach( (tid,id) -> p("\tThread "+tid+" was shared among tasks ids "+id));
        
        p("task-thread mappings recorded "+id2tid.size()+" distinct tasks");
        id2tid.values().removeIf(set -> set.size()<=1);
        id2tid.forEach( (id,tid) -> p("\tTask "+id+" was carried with thread ids "+tid));
    }
    
    static AbstractBlockingTask newTask(Class<? extends AbstractBlockingTask> clazz, int taskId, int delayms, BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> recorder) {
        AbstractBlockingTask t;
        try {
            t = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        t.taskId = taskId;
        t.indent = "\t".repeat(taskId) +"#";
        t.delayMs = delayms;
        t.recorder = recorder;
        return t;
    }
    
    static void runTasks(String title, boolean useVT, Supplier<Runnable> taskFactory) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        int N = 3 * cores;
        
        p("\n\n=========== "+title+" "+(useVT?"using VT":"using platform")+" threads ===============\n");
        p("Processors count  = " + cores+"; threads to create = " + N);
        
        long t0;
        long d;
        
        ExecutorService es = useVT ? Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() : Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(Thread.ofPlatform().factory());
        try (es) {
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            List<? extends Future<?>> futures = IntStream
                .range(0, N)
                .mapToObj(i -> taskFactory.get())
                .map(es::submit)
                .toList();
            
            //--------
            
            if(TRACELOG) p("waiting for all futures...");
            for(Future<?> future: futures) {
                        future.get();
            }
            d = System.nanoTime()-t0;
            if(TRACELOG) p("waiting futures took "+1e-9*d+" sec");
            
            //--------
            
            if(TRACELOG) p("shutting down es and await termination...");
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            es.shutdown();
            es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            d = System.nanoTime()-t0;
            if(TRACELOG) p("shut down took "+1e-9*d+" sec");
            
            //--------
            
            if(TRACELOG) p("closing executor...");
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
        }
        
        if(TRACELOG) p("closing executor took " + 1e-9*d + " sec");
    }
    
    
    static abstract class AbstractBlockingTask implements Runnable {
        int taskId;
        private int delayMs;
        private String indent;
        BiConsumer<Integer,Integer> recorder;
        
        AbstractBlockingTask() {
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(TRACELOG) p(indent + "task " + taskId + " started.");
            work();
            if(TRACELOG) p(indent + "task " + taskId + " ended.");
        }
        
        void work() {
            for(int i=1; i<=NUM_REPETITION; i++) {
                if(TRACELOG) p(indent + "call "+i+" starting ... ");
                try {
                    block(delayMs);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    p("call "+i+" interrupted!");
                }
                if(TRACELOG) p(indent + "call "+i+" finished.");
            }
        }
        
        abstract void block(int delayms) throws InterruptedException;
    }
    
    
    //======= blocking tasks variants ====================
    
    static class SyncWaitTask extends AbstractBlockingTask {
        @Override
        void block(int delayms) throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized(this) {
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
                this.wait(delayms);
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
            }
        }
    }
    
    static class SyncSleepTask extends AbstractBlockingTask {
        @Override
        void block(int delayms) throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized(this) {
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
                Thread.sleep(delayms);
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
            }
        }
    }
    
    static class RLWaitTask extends AbstractBlockingTask {
        ReentrantLock rl = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition cond = rl.newCondition();
        @Override
        void block(int delayms) throws InterruptedException {
            rl.lock();
            try {
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
                cond.await(delayms, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
            } finally {
                rl.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
    
    static class RLSleepTask extends AbstractBlockingTask {
        ReentrantLock rl = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition cond = rl.newCondition();
        @Override
        void block(int delayms) throws InterruptedException {
            rl.lock();
            try {
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
                Thread.sleep(delayms);
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
            } finally {
                rl.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
    
    static class SleepTask extends AbstractBlockingTask {
        @Override
        void block(int delayms) throws InterruptedException {
            recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
            Thread.sleep(delayms);
            recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
        }
    }
    
    static class NetTask extends AbstractBlockingTask {
        @Override
        void block(int delayms) throws InterruptedException {
            recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
            connectAndRead(PORT, delayms);
            recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
        }
    }
    
    static class SyncNetTask extends AbstractBlockingTask {
        @Override
        void block(int delayms) throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized(this) {
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
                connectAndRead(PORT, delayms);
                recorder.accept(tid(), taskId);
            }
        }
    }
    
    static Closeable startServer() throws IOException {
        ExecutorService exsvc = Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(Thread.ofPlatform().factory());
        
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        Future<?> f = exsvc.submit(() -> {
            try {
                while(!Thread.interrupted() && !ss.isClosed()) {
                    Socket s = ss.accept();
                    exsvc.submit(() -> serviceOne(s));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        
        return () -> {
            f.cancel(true);
            exsvc.shutdownNow();
            ss.close();
        };
    }
    
    static void serviceOne(Socket s) {
        try {
            try(s) {
                InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
                int delayms = dis.readInt();
                
                OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
                Thread.sleep(delayms);
                os.write(42);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    static void connectAndRead(int port, int delayms) {
        try (Socket s = new Socket("localhost", port)) {
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeInt(delayms);
            dos.flush();
            
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            is.read();//should be delayed
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}


I’m confused. Is this a solution to your problem? Or is this a clarification to your Question? If the second, you should be posting as an edit to the Question, not as an Answer.

a solution, containing more variations of the blocking phase, which reproduce finally what I could not with the code in the question.

Note that it is not enough to use ConcurrentHashMap when the values are TreeSet instances which you access outside the guarded update functions. The calls .add(taskId) and .add(tid) on the results of computeIfAbsent are not thread safe.

good catch on the treeset. I know I wrote a Collections.synchronizedSet() call in the old K32.main(), I must have been distracted just enough when writing the recorder. Thanks, I'll update soon.

Do I understand you correctly that even with updated test it is impossible to determine virtual threads' pinning without employing internal JDK features like jdk.tracePinnedThreads or JFR? Because if certain TID/platform thread disappears  from the scope of the test, it does not mean it is pinned because this platform thread might be instead returned to the pool of platform threads FTJ uses to mount virtual threads on and since then never be reclaimed again. Do you agree?

I don't rely at all on the thead ids I find and list. That is just bonus information, not even important to the test. It certainly is possible to determine with some confidence that a VT is pinned if, as I showed, a test with native threads finishes in time as predicted while a test with VTs doesn't (by 300% off the target here), particularly for tasks that do nothing but block.

Ohh?! Is it possible to rely on overall execution time for determination of pinning?! It may indicate internal JDK problems with virtual thread scheduling, which are, along with occasional hanging, always possible with version 21, but thread pinning is well-defined internal event which can be determined only, AFAIK, by internal JDK indicators like Djdk.tracePinnedThreads of JFR. Are you hunting down something which is not exactly a pinning? BTW, for me synchronized sleep test does not always lead to pinning, but overall execution time is always way outside of "platform" limits.
